# QR code scan and record creation

Tags: account

I want to scan QR code which contain name and address detail and want to create a account based on that data. can anyone please help me on the same. Its urgent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below link to read QR code in Salesforce1

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2014/02/reading-qr-codes-in-salesforce1.html

Comment: Hi Anurag, you should post relevant content from a link as well as the link itself—links can and do go stale over time meaning these answers are not of much use to others in the future.

Comment: You are right Lacey. I will remember this thing. Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following links which is help you to scan QR code with name and address.

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2013/02/salesforce-and-qr-server-integration.html

http://sfdcintegration.blogspot.in/2014/04/bar-code-and-qr-code-from-vf-pgae-to.html

Comment: Hi Sandip, you should post relevant content from a link as well as the link itself—links can and do go stale over time meaning these answers are not of much use to others in the future.